# Does _channel key guarantees that the process is forked one?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a key named `_channel` in the `process` object of a forked process. The key contains the following

```
_channel: {
    fd: null,
    writeQueueSize: 0,
    buffering: false,
    onread: [Function],
    sockets: {
        got: {},
        send: {}
    }
}
```

The source code of node.js says that the `setupChannel` function sets this (`_channel`) key.

I want to know would it be right to assume that to identify whether this process is master or forked one, we need to check if `_channel` key exist?

Also is there a documentation for Node.js source code?

Comment: If you see in child_process.js, `_channel` will be null once its disconnected. So I think you can't be sure whether its disconnected or not a forked process.

Comment: Is this just because you want to `fork` on the same js file that node ran initially, or do you specifically want to know about `_channel`?

Comment: Yes, want to fork the same file that node ran initially. However, I want to be able to differentiate in any file, whether it is a forked one or ran normally using `node file.js`

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is you want to be able to identify whether or not the current process is a child of any other process and if its able to send the message to the parent.

If its right then you can use the `connected` property of the `process` object, like:

```
if (process.connected) {
  // do something
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_disconnect)

> way to check if you can send messages is to see if the `child.connected` property is true.

It won't be present if the process doesn't have any parent, and it will be `false` if the child is already disconnected from the parent

Hope that helps :)